# html after include_once doesn't exist

Tags: php, html, mysql, session

I'm making a users table and I'm including a part of the table(the users) with a php page that I call with `include_once`.

after that include my html doesn't exist when I run the page(with localhost). the code isn't hidden, it simply doesn't exist.

**this is my table and include function:**

```
<form onsubmit="return confirm('are you sure that you want to delete this user?');" action="includes/delete_user-inc.php" method="post">

                    <div>
                        <h2>All purchesed products:</h2>
                    </div>
                                <div>
                                <table class="pt">
                                    <tr> <th class="t">Id</th>
                                        <th class="t">Userame</th>
                                        <th class="t">Email</th>
                                        <th class="t">delete</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php 
                                        include_once 'includes/manage_users-inc.php';
                                        ?>
                                </table>                       
                                </div>  
                                    </form>
```

*any html after this point doesn't show in the file*

**the php code:**

```
<?php 

require 'dbh-inc.php';

$id = $_SESSION['userId'];
 if(!isset($id))
    {
        header("Location:../login.php");
        exit();

    }
$num=-1;

                    $sql = "SELECT idUsers, uidUsers, emailUsers FROM users;";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                    if($result->num_rows > 0){
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        $num = $num +1;

                      echo  "<tr><td>".$row['idUsers'].
                          "</td><td>". $row['uidUsers'].
                          "</td><td>". $row['emailUsers'].
                          "</td><td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit[" . $row['idUsers'] . "]\" value=\"delete user\" class=\"button\"></td></tr>" ;
                    }    
                    } 
exit();
?>
```

what do I need to do to fix the html disappearing?
thanks!

**Update:** *I was wrongly mistaken that every php script has to have an exit() function. while including a script, using the exit() function will exit the parent page and only the including page. 
include injects code into another page, it doesn't "call" another page.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the

```
exit();
```

line in the include file, because it's causing the main script to exit before printing the rest of the HTML.